# What does `Failed to get account keys because address table lookups were not resolved` mean?

Tags: phantom, lookup-tables

I have a transaction that works once building it using VersionedTransaction as well as legacy one.

```
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: payer,
      recentBlockhash: blockhash,
      instructions: ixs,
    }).compileToV0Message();
```

Now I create&populate a lookup table and I verify in the explorer that my lookup table is correct as has some accounts on it.

Then I create the same transaction and include the previous lookup table and if my understanding is correct, the transaction should work.

```
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: payer,
      recentBlockhash: blockhash,
      instructions: ixs,
    }).compileToV0Message([lookupTable]);
```

Instead the tx fails with the following error
`Failed to get account keys because address table lookups were not resolved`
The error seems to be triggered from here
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/8f5ba1b0fce3d4b60fee4a4aeb78a83d2c7b2b93/src/message/v0.ts#L105
What is the issue?
As if the function [decompile](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/src/transaction/message.ts#L35) is being called without a proper argument.

**Update**
The error seems happening when signing the transaction with the Phantom wallet while it works using Solflare

Why is this happening?

Comment: This looks like it's a bug within Phantom. We have a fix pending review, will post an answer here with the version number once the fix is live.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was a bug in an application, not due to Solana development

Answer (score 1):

This has now been fixed in Phantom v23.1.0!